# Laravel add content to every rendered view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-middleware

Is there any way to add content to every rendered view to Laravel 5.5 project? I would like to require one Composer package which for example adds some JavaScript code to every rendered view without any modification to actual project code.

Now I have implemented this by creating view into package and including it into my layout header, but it would be better if this can be done somehow without manual include.

Comment: I know [debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) currently implements this behaviour so yes it is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use middleware for this. You can modify response adding any piece of code you want for example this code adds additional piece of code before `</head>` in html when running tests:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    /** @var Response $response */
    $response = $next($request);
    if ($response instanceof Response && app()->runningUnitTests() &&
        str_contains($response->headers->get('Content-Type'), 'text/html')) {
        $content = $response->getContent();
        if (($head = mb_strpos($content, '</head>')) !== false) {
            $response->setContent(mb_substr($content, 0, $head) .
                '<style>' . $this->config->get('laravel_test_css.style') . '</style>' .
                mb_substr($content, $head));
        }
    }
    return $response;
}
```

(this is piece of code of my middleware - full file - https://github.com/mnabialek/laravel-test-css/blob/master/src/Middleware/LaravelTestCss.php )

If you want to apply this middleware globally you can do something like this:

```
app('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel')->pushMiddleware(CustomMiddleware::class);
```

Comment: Do I need to configure the middleware in use in routes in this case? I'm looking fully automated solution that so only composer require is needed.

Comment: Assuming you use `web` group middleware it's enough to add this in `app/Http/Kernel.php` to `web` group

Comment: Yes, you're right. But then it's not fully automated. Almost same than including the file to layout template blade.

Comment: @lingo I've updated with the way you can push your custom middleware to HTTP middleware stack. If you add this into package service provider it won't be necessary to add this manually in application

Answer (score 0):

> Occasionally, you may need to share a piece of data with all views that are rendered by your application. You may do so using the view facade's share method. Typically, you should place calls to share within a service provider's boot method. You are free to add them to the `AppServiceProvider` or generate a separate service provider to house them

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

Or you could use a view composer:

> The composer method also accepts the `*` character as a wildcard, allowing you to attach a composer to all views:

```
View::composer('*', function ($view) {
    //
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#view-composers

Comment: It's not that simply because I don't play only with variables. I like to include content to every rendered view.

Comment: @lingo if it's HTML/JS/CSS you can add it to the main layout blade file. BTW, all high-quality packages I saw use composers. So, you can render some dynamic JS for example.

Comment: We're not talking about automated implementation if I need to include it into layout manually. Composers are for different things. I did this using middlewares - please read another answer also.